# How can I fix things when LaTex issues a package minted error for "Pygments" or pigmentize?

Tags: macos, terminal, python, latex

I am trying to install the "Pygments" package to Python via terminal on my Mac so that I can utilize the "minted" package in Latex.

I have downloaded the package via the terminal by using the following code:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py
```

followed by:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

and then

```
sudo pip install pygments
```

It took a couple tries of repeating the same commands but it finally successfully installed. I don't know what to do now though. I'm still getting the same error from LaTex:

```
Package minted Error: You must have `pigmentize' installed to use this package.
```

Does anyone have any experience with this issue and could possibly provide some assistance?

Comment: Why not just `sudo pip install pygments` as given on the pygments home page ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First, Locate the folder where pygmentize is saved

   ```
   $ which pygmentize 
   /Users/ggautier/anaconda/bin/pygmentize
   ```
2. Add the path i.e. /Users/ggautier/anaconda/bin in the "texpath" field

---

```
// Platform settings: adapt as needed for your machine
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

 "osx":  {
  // Path used when invoking tex & friends; MUST include $PATH
  "texpath" : "$PATH:/Users/ggautier/anaconda/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:"
  // Path to PDF viewer, if needed
  // TODO think about it. Also, maybe configure it here!
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, where am I writing this? In the terminal?

Comment: @G.P.: You run the first command in the terminal to know where is the file located. Once you know the location, open it and edit the file and add the path as shared in step 2.